# Update ContentProvider after sqlite download

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Some of my apps content is downoaded from the web in the form of an sqlite database.

Once downloaded this database provides a list of stores.

The issue I'm running into is that the onCreate() method of the ContentProvider is called at app start up, before the sqlite database is downloaded.

I'm just testing now, but when I go to my AutoCompleteTextView and start typing my app crashes, likely because the database was not available when the ContentProvider was initiated.

When I reopen the app, everything works as expected.

Is there something I can do to reload the database once the download is complete? I'm having trouble because in the fragment where the AutoCompleteTextView is I'm using a CursorLoader, so I don't ever instantiate the ContentProvider ... I just use the loader. So there is no way for me to call something like ContentProvider.reloadDatabase().

One thing I found that does work is closing-reopening the database in my .query() method in the ContentProvider. But this is extremely inefficient, as this is called every time a new character is typed in the AutoCompleteTextView.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I ended up adding a listener method to my sqlite-updater (extends AsyncTask). When the download completes it calls the listener method and updates  the contentprovider